# Selecting th in table.th.tr vs table.tbody.tr for two types of tables

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have hundreds of HTML files and I need to restyle table headers in the global css. Some have a thead and some do not. So I can style the thead, but for the tables that don't have a thead, I style the first tr. Well, of course that applies the style to the first row of tables that have a thead also, resulting in those tables having two rows of header style.
I have tried getting the hierarchy correct for those that don't have a thead

```
tbody:first-child tr:first-child td
```

However I cannot separately style these two types of tables. Any ideas would be very helpful. Unfortunately cannot use JavaScript.

```
<div class="tablenoborder">
    <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" summary="" class="table" frame="border" border="1" rules="all">
        <tbody class="tbody">
            <tr class="row">
                <td class="entry" valign="top">
                    <strong class="ph b">Option</strong>
                </td>
                <td class="entry" valign="top">
                    <strong class="ph b">Description</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="tablenoborder">
    <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" summary="" class="table" frame="border" border="1" rules="all">
        <thead class="thead" align="left">
            <tr class="row">
                <th class="entry" valign="top" id="d29429e118">UI Elements</th>
                <th class="entry" valign="top" id="d29429e121">Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="tbody">
            <tr class="row">
                <td class="entry" valign="top" headers="d29429e118 ">Language</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you want to assign class to each of your element inside a table? Just assign a class to your table and access the child element like `.my_table th`, or `.my_table td` and so on...

Comment: thanks much. I really don't want to go into 500+ files and add classes to tables. That's the problem. These two types of existing tables are structured differently so I thought there should be a way to say "apply header style to thead if there is one, and  to first tr IFF there is no thead"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this selector:

```
.table > :first-child > tr:first-child > * {
    /* ... */
}
```

`:first-child` will match both `thead` or `tbody` and from there you select direct children of `tr` elements which are `th` (inside a `thead`) or `td` (inside `tbody`).

Check the demo below.

```css
.table > :first-child > tr:first-child > * {
    background: #EEE;
}

.tablenoborder {margin-bottom: 10px;}
```

```html
<div class="tablenoborder">
    <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" summary="" class="table" frame="border" border="1" rules="all">
        <tbody class="tbody">
            <tr class="row">
                <td class="entry" valign="top">
                    <strong class="ph b">Option</strong>
                </td>
                <td class="entry" valign="top">
                    <strong class="ph b">Description</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row">
                <td class="entry" valign="top">
                    <strong class="ph b">Option</strong>
                </td>
                <td class="entry" valign="top">
                    <strong class="ph b">Description</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="tablenoborder">
    <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" summary="" class="table" frame="border" border="1" rules="all">
        <thead class="thead" align="left">
            <tr class="row">
                <th class="entry" valign="top" id="d29429e118">UI Elements</th>
                <th class="entry" valign="top" id="d29429e121">Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="tbody">
            <tr class="row">
                <td class="entry" valign="top" headers="d29429e118 ">Language</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! however that styles the thead in the thead tables and ALL the rows in the tables without a thead. I would also have expected this to work!

Comment: yes, my bad, check updated answer, you need also `tr:first-child`.

Comment: Just hope there are no tables with caption or colgroup elements.